# Issue converting from Y/m/d to Y-m-d using $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to convert the brackets to hyphens, but instead the date variable loses its value:

```
echo $date; // outputs 26/05/2015 10:41:56sd2

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);

echo $date; // outputs 969-12-31 18:00:26
```

Answer (score 4):

1. The second parameter to `date()` must be a Unix timestamp. You're giving it a string.
2. That date format is invalid and won't work with `strtotime()` anyway. When you  use `/` as the date separator US format is assumed. There is no 26th month.
3. The last three characters of that is not valid in any standard that I know of and will break any date function unless you specifically account for it (which you can't do with `date()` or `strtotime()`)

Use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to do this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s???', '26/05/2015 10:41:56sd2');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/370843)

Comment: amending the above code with your suggestion gives me a syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: The code above works as shown in the demo so you have a syntax error elsewhere. I can;t tell you where it is as i don't know your code but the error message should tell you what  line it occurs on.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?